# wxPython memory leak with setValue

Tags: wxpython

I run the following code under Mac OS X 10.6.8, wxPython 2.9.3.1 and 64 Bit Python v2.7.2:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame,self).__init__(None, title="Frame", size=(100, 100))
        self.field = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Text", (30, 7))
    def startLoop(self):
        counter = 0
        while True:
            counter += 1
            self.field.SetValue(str(counter))
            wx.Yield()
class Main(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        super(Main,self).__init__(0)

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.frame.startLoop()
        self.MainLoop()
        return True
Main()
```

It just uses up more an more memory. Am I doing something horribly wrong or is wxPython so badly broken? And most importantly is there a workaround because I already programmed a huge GUI based on wxPython.

Thank you so much!

wx.StaticText leaks exactly the same in the above code.

Comment: Possibly implementation specific, I'm past 3m iterations and python hasn't budged above its original 26M memory.  Win7, python32 2.2.7, wxpython 2.8.12.1

Comment: Interesting. It goes over 100 MB after half a minute and keeps growing on my computer.

Comment: Maybe try testing Mike Driscoll's theory and either remove wx.Yield(), or do it only every thousand / million iterations and see if it affects growth?  Regardless, I agree this is unexpected & you may have to go to the wxpython list for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike's answer is at least partially correct, it's always a good idea to avoid wx.Yield if you can.  After switching to using EVT_IDLE events there is still an apparent memory leak, although it is much smaller and slower than before.  Switching to a wx.StaticText instead of a wx.TextCtrl shows no leak at all, so there appears to indeed be a problem related to wx.TextCtrl.SetValue.  Please make a ticket about this at trac.wxwidgets.org with the component set to wxOSX-cocoa and include a link to this page.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame,self).__init__(None, title="Frame", size=(100, 100))
        ##self.field = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Text", (30, 7))
        self.field = wx.StaticText(self)

    def startIdle(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.onIdle)

    def onIdle(self, evt):
        self.counter += 1
        ##self.field.SetValue(str(self.counter))
        self.field.SetLabel(str(self.counter))
        evt.RequestMore()


class Main(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.frame.startIdle()
        self.MainLoop()
        return True
Main()
```

Comment: Thank you! I used wx.StaticText before in my GUI (not in the example) and the leak was much bigger. As soon as I am in the office I will test your solution. In my real code I update the GUI once a second using join(1) in a loop waiting for threads. But because the programm is running for a long time this becomes a issue.

Comment: Now I switched back to StaticText and using a Timer to update the GUI once a second and it still leaks. But probably it is the progress bar or something. There are other functions leaking even more like  Layout(). I cannot understand how this could get through bug testing. I mean it breaks the whole wx.Python on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're calling wx.Yield too often and the events are stacking up. I doubt your GUI is very responsive either. A better way would be to just use a wx.Timer and have it periodically update the label. You would have to ask on the wxPython mailing list to get the really technical answer.

Answer (score 1):

OSX has the concept of autorelease pools, ie many OS 'temporary' objects only get cleaned after an iteration through the event loop, your tight loop never gives the OS the chance to clean anything, calling yield does not help here.

The reason for the memory consumption in Robin's idle implementation when using the textctrl is the fact that - as long as the textfield has the focus - it stores everything in its undo-stack, this memory is only reclaimed when the focus changes. I'll see whether I can turn this off automatically.

Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: I've added a fix to svn-trunk, that turns off undo for the setter, [http://trac.wxwidgets.org/changeset/72166](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/changeset/72166)

Comment: Ok, thank you alot! I was able to work around the bug by using a timer that does not update too often and StaticText instead of CtrlText. The problem is that my application is very cpu intensive in multiple threads. This probably gives wx not alot of cpu time to do clean up stuff. So a method to do it manually would be great.